# Example of i.d. random variables s.t. $\frac{X_n}{n} \not\rightarrow 0 ~~~a.s.$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

I am looking for a counterexample to the following statement:

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of identically distributed random variables, then

$$ \frac{X_n}{n} \rightarrow 0 ~~~a.s.$$

---

The statement is true when the $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are i.i.d. and all $X_n \in L^1$.
Also, the statement is true for convergence in probability since

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0: \mathbb{P}\left(\left\vert \frac{X_n}{n} \right\vert > \varepsilon\right) = \mathbb{P}(\vert X_n \vert > \varepsilon n) \rightarrow 0$$

My first try was to modify the usual example of a sequence converging in probability but not almost surely (i.e., typewriter sequence). However, that forces the random variables to have different distributions.

Any tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Feels like something like a Cauchy random variable may work (or not but that's my best guess)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider an i.i.d. sequence $\{X_n\}$. Since
$$
\sum_{n\ge 1}\mathsf{P}(|X_1|>n)\ge \int_{1}^{\infty} \mathsf{P}(|X_1|>x)\, dx \ge \mathsf{E}|X_1|-1,
$$
and the events $\{|X_n|>n\}$, $n\ge 1$, are independent, the 2nd Borel-Cantelli lemma implies that
$$
\mathsf{P}(|X_n|>n\text{ i.o.})=1
$$
whenever $\mathsf{E}|X_1|=\infty$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are showing

Comment: What exactly is not clear?

Comment: How does that answer my question? I am only considering identically distributed RVs, not iid

Comment: i.i.d. RVs are i.d. RVs.

Comment: I see, so you're saying any iid sequence which is not $L^1$ gives an example, right?